# Как узнать ID процесса, который поставил хук на WinAPI функцию?

Tags: windows, winapi, hook

Товарищи. Недавно потребовалось решить задачу с нахождением ID процесса, который поставил хук на определенную функцию. Уже несколько дней ломаю голову, поиск по Интернету особо ничего не дал. Возможно, здесь кто-то уже решал подобную задачу. Код полный не прошу, хотя бы направление, куда двигаться.

Comment: Какого типа хук?

Comment: @Zergatul глобальный, в данном случае рассматриваю хук на нажатие клавиш.

Comment: Возможно... вызов CallMsgFilter - прояснит ситуацию... Только что б рекурсию не вызвал. Если вернулось true - то это сообщение точно подверглось хуку.

Comment: Можно... дизассемблером покопать... наверняка цепочка где-то хранится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможный вариант. Пишите длл-ку, которая перехватывает вызов `SetWindowsHookEx`, инжектите ее в каждый процесс (самый простой способ через `AppInit_DLLs`). Как только процесс попытается создать хук, вы это увидите в своем коде. Вы увидите его `PID`, и сможете еще много чего сделать (например заблокировать создание хука).

Comment: ответ приму, так как действительно здравая мысль, но, к сожалению, я решил отказаться от хуков в проекте, слишком много придется перехватывать (хук на клаву - это один из немногих)